# One hot encoding with variable length inputs

Tags: python, encoding, keras, one-hot-encoding

I'm having trouble doing one-hot encoding on sequences of variable length. I have a dictionary with 21 characters, and I want all my outputs to be of dimension (length, 21). Currently, I have a list of approx 4000 sequences that have been tokenized(i.e. they are all numerical) of variable length.

The problem is now, I cannot call the `keras.utils.to_categorical` function on the list of length 4000 because the elements are of varying size. To try to get over this, tried to convert them to one hot encoding element wise.

The problem with this is I get various secondary dimensions, i.e. I'll get (length, 20), (length,18), etc. Any ideas? Here's the broken code for reference. (train_aa_seq is the list of length 4000).

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(char_level = True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_aa_seq)
X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_aa_seq)
X_train_ERROR = to_categorical(X_train) ##THIS WONT WORK
# X_train = X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen = maxlen, padding = 'post')
for i in range(len(X_train)):
    X_train_example = to_categorical(X_train[i])
    print(X_train_example.shape)
    # WORKS BUT WRONG SECOND DIMENSION
```